# PowerMockito: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while mocking static method using PowerMickito

Tags: java, powermockito

I am trying to mock static method

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ABC.class);
Mockito.when(ABC.selectSingleValue(any(java.sql.Connection.class), any(String.class), Matchers.<Object>anyVararg())).thenReturn("TestStatic");
```

Below is the exception which i am getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.matchers.LocalizedMatcher.getMatcher()Lorg/mockito/ArgumentMatcher;
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.PowerMockMatchersBinder.extractArgumentMatchers(PowerMockMatchersBinder.java:60)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.PowerMockMatchersBinder.bindMatchers(PowerMockMatchersBinder.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl.performIntercept(MockitoMethodInvocationControl.java:275)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl.invoke(MockitoMethodInvocationControl.java:201)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:173)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:155)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:132)
    a
```

Comment: this seems a version problem to me, which versions are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I was using PowerMock 1.7.4, while using Mockito 2.22.0. I resolved the issue by consulting the [compatibility table](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions) and seeing that I had to downgrade Mockito to 2.8.9. Once I did, the exception stopped appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at doc for latest stable release on maven central:

[doc for 1.10.19](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/internal/matchers/LocalizedMatcher.html#getMatcher())

There is no getMatcher method.

It seems it has been added later in the beta version as you can see from

[this doc for 2.0.40-beta](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.0.40-beta/org/mockito/internal/matchers/LocalizedMatcher.html#getMatcher())

```
getMatcher
    public ArgumentMatcher getMatcher()
```

Comment: I am using mockito-core-2.0.43-beta.jar

Answer (score 0):

It's a version compatibility issue. If you're using Mockito 1.10.8 - 1.10.x, the you should use module `powermock-api-mockito` 1.6.2. 
If you want use Mockito 2 (looks like you use it), then you should use module `powermock-api-mockito2`. it's recommended to use PowerMock 1.7.0RC4.

More information about version compatibility you may find [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage)

Comment: The following are the jars which i am using it.                                                   powermock-api-mockito2-1.6.6.jar, powermock-api-mockito-common-1.6.6.jar, powermock-api-support-1.6.6.jar, powermock-core-1.6.6.jar, powermock-module-junit4-1.6.6.jar, powermock-module-junit4-common-1.6.6.jar, powermock-reflect-1.6.6.jar, mockito-core-2.0.43-beta.jar, javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar